# Error while restoring svn repository backup

Tags: svn, svnadmin, svn-repository

I am using Subversion (SVN) on ubuntu machine and now want to move subversion to windows machine so I did the following steps

> Copy svn repository by using following command

svnadmin dump /path/to/reponame > /path/to/reponame.bak

> Installed SVN on windows machine and created new repository on that and
>   tried to restore backup by using following command

svnadmin load /path/to/reponame < /path/to/reponame.bak

restoring takes place until rev 11 then I get this error msg:

```
 <<< Started new transaction, based on original revision 12
 * adding path : vs ...svnadmin: E160020: File already exists: filesystem '7424b5b4-637a-e843-a697-d0752184fe09', transaction '899-r9', path '/vs'
```

Is there any thing that I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

You're not actually loading the dump file into a new repository.

There are two clues to this in the error message:

1. The phrase, `based on original revision` means that svnadmin is altering the revision numbers as it goes because the repository is at some different revision than the one provided.
2. The transaction id is listed as 899-r9.  Transaction ids are composed of two parts.  The first portion (899 in this case) is the revision number it is based on.  The second part (r9 in this case) is a base36 encoded counter.  So the transaction is based on revision 899 yet you said it only committed up to revision 11.

The error is happening because the repository you're loading it into already has a path named `vs`, probably because it's another copy of the same repository.